# How can I search a string in more than ten columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I want search a string in all 10 columns in a SQL table. How can I do it in SQL?

For example :

I have to search “Computer” word in all ten columns or all the columns in a single table .

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use "OR" operator.

For Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE (col1 LIKE '%searchstring%') OR (col2 LIKE '%searchstring%') OR (col3 LIKE '%searchstring%')
```